# python:if statement followed by a variable(word)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering what does the 'dec' in "if dec: " means on line 3

```
  1 def dec2bin(dec):
  2         result=''
  3         if dec:                                                             
  4                 result = dec2bin(dec//2)
  5                 return result + str(dec%2)
  6         else:
  7                 return result
  8 print(dec2bin(62))
```

Comment: So does that means "if dec ==True:"?

Comment: Not quite. `if bool(dec) == True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if dec` is checking the truthyness of the value with the name `dec`.

In your case, dec is a number, which will evaluate to `False` (or more precisely, `bool(dec)` will be `False`) if and only if it is equal to 0.0 or 0.

In case the number `dec` is not 0.0 or 0, `dec2bin` is called recursively, otherwise the `else` clause is executed and the result is returned.

You can check the truthyness of a value with the built in `bool` function. As a rule of thumb, zero-values and any kind of empty containers are falsy:

```
>>> bool(23)
True
>>> bool(0.0)
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2,3])
True
>>> 
>>> if 23:
...     'will show'
... 
'will show'
>>> if 0:
...     'wont show'
... 
>>>
```

Comment: Here's a reference for you @C.Quian. Chances are, as you develop your code and things get more complex, you will have booleans everywhere and it's nice to know what's going on when they get tossed into conditionals.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table